# How do I branch using SVN on CodePlex?

Tags: svn, branch, codeplex

Unless I am missing something very obvious, I don't see how I can branch on CodePlex using SVN. I'm looking at the popular projects and can't see anything about a trunk or branches.

What am I missing? Also, I'm using TortoiseSVN.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SO folks have shed some light on this here: [How to use an Internet Subversion respository when developing code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1046216/how-to-use-an-internet-subversion-respository-when-developing-code) - you might want to take a look and revisit how you want to go about your task. Hope this helps.